# Colorbox in IE8 throwing a wobbly

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, colorbox

This problem occurs in Firefox and Chrome, but Safari is fine. IE8, however, in compatability mode or not, doesn't load the overlay over the top (it just sits at the top, scrolling the content down - although I guess this is because the overlay is at the top of the markup).

It also doesn't show the image I'm attempting to show, but shrinks the overlay loading image to nothing in the top left of the screen.  I am using the standard colorbox-min and the CSS that goes with that.

Inspecting the markup in the IE8 dev tools seems to hint that the content is not actually loaded into the cboxLoadedContent div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel="preview"]').colorbox(
        { 
            photo: true
            , maxWidth: '95%'
            , maxHeight: '95%'
            , photoScaling: true 
        }
    ); 
});
```

basically the page is a list of media images and when you click one it gives you the preview and allows you to scroll through ones on the page
well at least it does in FF took a little screenshot as it was shrinking the overlay thingy http://dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=7s2zwoxozzf7666h0fzc.png

Anyone have any ideas?

I expect my explanation is not great, so maybe I could take a movie of it or something if needed.

Comment: +1 for the same reason. Thankyou

Comment: Does your page have any validation errors? That can throw colorbox off in some browsers. Anything obvious get flagged if you chuck your HTML through http://validator.w3.org ?

Comment: another +1 for the title, hillarious!

Comment: Do you have an example we may view? I always find it helpful with JavaScript bugs to have access to a page exhibiting the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code wrapped in a ready function?  I've seen instances where code that works in FF/Safari fails in IE because IE seems to load the DOM more slowly.  In those cases it almost always turns out that I've failed to wrap the code in a ready function.

```
$(function() { // the important bit
    $('.colorbox').load('...').colorbox();
});
```

Comment: hi , thanks for the reply...
no sadly its in a ready 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a[rel="preview"]').colorbox({ photo: true, maxWidth: '95%', maxHeight: '95%', photoScaling: true });
});

basically the page is a list of media images.. and when you click one it gives you the preview and allows you to scroll through ones on the page.. well it does in FF

took a little screenshot as it was shrinking the overlay thingy
http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=7s2zwoxozzf7666h0fzc.png
so that is getting smaller to nothing, then that is all it does

Comment: @nat - Perhaps it's not waiting on the images to load and calculating sizes incorrectly in IE?  Try something simple, like delaying the set up for a minute (to give the images a chance to load).  `$('a...').delay(60000)...`  or setTimeout( function() { $('a...') }, 600000 );`  If that works, then you may need to adjust your code to either detect when the images are loaded or use a container with some minimum size.

Comment: ok i have now replaced the colorbox js and css, and it may in fact be a css problem, although i cant see why
using completely standard bits..
using the new standard css the image does actually load, but overlay dies and some other bits dont look quite right
how i hate IE is absolute rubbish
thanks v much for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Try an XHTML strict doctype...?

Comment: Even a Transitional one fixed a very similar problem for me,  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the exact same symptoms - but in my case it extended to all browsers.

One cause was that I didn't include the CSS file that I use for pages that use colorbox.

Another cause was I updated to the newest version of jQuery, but didn't upgrade colorbox. (Also, if you update your jquery include, make sure that you also update your jquery vs doc - if you're even using it).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Search through your colorbox files for this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
```

There will be several instances of it, each pointing to a png. Make sure the path to that png is correct, then test it again.

I'm pretty sure I had this exact problem at one point, and fixing the paths was all I needed to do. However, it's been a while so my memory is a little fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I also had a problem with the image being only 10px wide due to IE not liking CSS max-width being set to 100%.  To alleviate the problem I add the following to my CSS.

```
.cboxIE img
   {
        max-width:none;
         _max-width:none;
   }
```